# Error : XXX is null on angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I encountered this error :

`ERROR : DISCIPLINE.EVENTS is NULL`

It's raised by the second `if` statement.

Here's the code :

```
angular.forEach($scope.form.disciplines, function(discipline) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(discipline.events) || discipline.events == null){ 
            angular.forEach(discipline.compets, function(compet) { 
                var key = compet.eventCode;
                if (angular.isUndefined(discipline.events[key]) || discipline.events[key] == null) {
                    discipline.events[key] = {fhi:{presented : null, box : null, notAccepted : null, withdrawn : null, accepted : null}}                         }
            });                              
        }   
    });
```

Thanks to all .

Comment: try to delete it angular.isUndefined(discipline.events) i think it comes from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize `discipline.events` to an empty array before the inner `forEach`:

```js
if (...) {
    discipline.events = [];
    angular.forEach(
        ...
    );                              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is here, `discipline.events` doesn't to be an array, equals null :

```
discipline.events[key]
```

Before get value of an array, test if events is not null or is an array. Like this :

```
if (!discipline.events || angular.isUndefined(discipline.events[key]) || discipline.events[key] == null) {
```

Or maybe :

```
if (typeof(discipline.events) == "object" || /*...*/) {
```